# How to converting JSON text to PHP associative array

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON Object stored in a text file(data.txt):

```
{"player":"black","time":"0","from":"2c","to":"3d"}
```

Which i read using php:

```
<?php
  $data = file_get_contents('data.txt');
?>
```

**Question:** Is there an easy way to convert `$data` to a PHP associative array. I have tried using `json_decode($data);` but that did not work, any suggestions?

Comment: Why did `json_decode($data)` not work?

Comment: Because the JSON is coming from a text file and PHP reads it as a string.

Comment: You may have to encode the string into json. Then put it into an array..

Comment: JSON === string. If your text file contains the string you have posted above, it should be `json_decodable` just fine.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$assocArray = json_decode($data, true);
```

The second parameter set the result as an object(false, default) or an associative array(true).

Comment: Make sure you don't get your single and double quotes mixed up:
//valid JSON: 
  $string = '{"foo": "bar", "cool": "attr"}';

//Invalid JSON:
 $string = "{'foo': 'bar', 'cool': 'attr'}";

See: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 3):

Try:
`json_decode($data, true)`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

It worked for me. Also, make sure your PHP version has json_encode / json_decode

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to convert array from json in php, this can validate if the provided string is valid json or not:

```
function convert_to_json($file, $in_array = True) {
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        $string = file_get_contents($file);
    }else {
        $string = $file;
    }

    $return_array = json_decode($string, $in_array);
    if (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        return $return_array;
    }

    return False;
}
```