# How to decode this type of JSON in php

Tags: php, json

any idea how to decode this type of json in php?

```
a:3{s:9:"signature";s:43:"a:1{s:17:"ThemeShiftOptions";s:5:"0.1.2";}";s:5:"items";s:22984:"a:85:{i:1;O:8:"stdClass":7{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:7:"item_id";s:15:"general_default";s:10:"item_title";s:7:"General";s:9:"item_desc";s:0:"";s:9:"item_type";s:7:"heading";s:12:"item_options
```

Comment: have you tried json_decode() ?

Comment: Doesn't seem like valid json.

Comment: What you have given is not valid json

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to converting JSON text to PHP associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264724/how-to-converting-json-text-to-php-associative-array)

Comment: @Khushboo, yes i try to decode in json_decode($jsonString, true); but is not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not JSON, but rather some data serialized with PHP's `serialize()`.

To [unserialize()](http://php.net/unserialize) it, simply:

```
$data = unserialize($string);
```

Comment: Thanks @Qualcuno, it worked. sorry i didn't know what type that's thing. i though is a type is  json, thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true); // use true if you want to get an array
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like JSON to me:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Explain the example so others que users are interested in your answer and give up-votes, remember the answer have to be so good for the community and for the individual :)

Comment: The author's code is not JSON, however, but it's PHP serialized objects

Comment: Thanks @Qualcuno, sorry i didn't know what type that's thing. i though is a type is json, thanks anyway